# Cannot boot after hard shutdown

Tags: boot, 22.04, boot-partition

I overloaded my memory which caused ubuntu to freeze. I shutdown the computer by pressing the power button for a few seconds. When turning it on I see a message saying something like "no bootable media found" (not the exact wording).

After googling around I tried fdisk: sudo fdisk /dev/sda (from a bootable USB). But fdisk returned the error "Device does not contain a recognized partition table"

I also noticed that when GParted looks at my disk it says "unallocated" no partitions (I had a swap partition, a Windows partition, and a linux partition. Possibly a separate home partition too) and no filesystem.

Does this look like I can recover my partitions and installations? Does it look like my HD might still be ok and at the very least do a fresh install? Are there some diagnostics I should run first?

Edit: I ran testdisk but it did not find a partition table. It seems like my partition table has been lost. Does this mean my filesystem may still be there and is recoverable?